# Writing to Cosmos DB Graph API from Databricks (Apache Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

I have a `DataFrame` in Databricks which I want to use to create a graph in Cosmos, with one row in the `DataFrame` equating to 1 vertex in Cosmos.

When I write to Cosmos I can't see any properties on the vertices, just a generated id.

Get data:

```
data = spark.sql("select * from graph.testgraph")
```

Configuration:

```
writeConfig = {
 "Endpoint" : "******",
 "Masterkey" : "******",
 "Database" : "graph",
 "Collection" : "TestGraph",
 "Upsert" : "true",
 "query_pagesize" : "100000",
 "bulkimport": "true",
 "WritingBatchSize": "1000",
 "ConnectionMaxPoolSize": "100",
 "partitionkeydefinition": "/id"
}
```

Write to Cosmos:

```
data.write.
  format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").
  options(**writeConfig).
  save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code to insert records into cosmos DB.
go to the below site, click on the download option and select the uber.jar
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11/1.2.2/jar then add in your dependency

spark-shell --master yarn --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 10g --num-executors 10 --driver-memory 10g --jars "path/to/jar/dependency/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.2.2-uber.jar" --packages "com.google.guava:guava:18.0,com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1,com.microsoft.azure:azure-documentdb:1.16.1"

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val data = Seq(
Row(2, "Abb"),
Row(4, "Bcc"),
Row(6, "Cdd")
)

val schema = List(
StructField("partitionKey", IntegerType, true),
StructField("name", StringType, true)
)

val DF = spark.createDataFrame(
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
StructType(schema)
)

val writeConfig = Map("Endpoint" -> "https://*******.documents.azure.com:443/",
"Masterkey" -> "**************",
"Database" -> "db_name",
"Collection" -> "collection_name",
"Upsert" -> "true",
"query_pagesize" -> "100000",
"bulkimport"-> "true",
"WritingBatchSize"-> "1000",
"ConnectionMaxPoolSize"-> "100",
"partitionkeydefinition"-> "/partitionKey")

DF.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("overwrite").options(writeConfig).save()
```